# Microsoft office 12.0 access database engine not showing up as provider

Tags: ms-access, delphi, delphi-2010

The Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine is not showing up as a provider when i try to build a connection. I tried installing the engine again, but it did not fix the issue. What could be the problem

I downloaded the engine from https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=13255 and installed it, but it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Which DB components do you use?

Comment: You probably installed the 64-bit version, which isn't seen by the 32-bit IDE.